# How does CLLocation implement the Equatable protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, equatable

In answering another question on SO, I found that the `CLLocation` class conforms to the `Equatable` protocol. What method does it use to determine equality?

Exact match of lat/long? Exact match of lat/long and altitude? Exact match of latitude, longitude, altitude, and timestamp? What about speed and course? What about `CLLocation` objects that were created with only a lat/long pair? Various other values of the location are not optionals, so what would the altitude be for a location created using `init(latitude:longitude:)`?

Comment: By inheriting from `NSObject`?  If you try to call `==` with two `CLLocation` objects, you will see that the function used is the one declared for `NSObject`: `public func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool`.  The "correct" way to compare two `CLLocation` instances would probably be to use `distance(from:)` and compare that to a `CLLocationDistance` threshold.

Comment: If you want to know what properties are used to determine equality you should run a few tests with various values and see what the results are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fully verify what JAL has said in his answer, I wrote:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var cl1 = CLLocation()
    var cl2 = CLLocation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if cl1 == cl2{

        }
    }
}
```

Then I command clicked on the `==` (from `if cl1 == cl2`). It took me to:

```
extension NSObject : CVarArg {
}

public func ==(lhs: Selector, rhs: Selector) -> Bool

public func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool

public struct NSZone {
}
```

To double check I command clicked on `CLLocation` and saw:

```
open class CLLocation : NSObject, NSCopying, NSSecureCoding {
...
}
```

So basically the `==` is because it's subclassed from `NSObject` which only compares references.

Comment: misleading implementation. `==` maps to `===`.

Answer (score 2):

> How does `CLLocation` implement the Equatable protocol?

It doesn't.  There is no overridden `==` function which compares two `CLLocation` instances. When calling `==` with two `CLLocation` instances, the `NSObject` `==` function is used:

```
public func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool
```

To actually compare two `CLLocation` instances, either compare the properties on each you care about (latitude or longitude), or use the built in `distance(from:)` method with two locations and compare that to a `CLLocationDistance` threshold.

Comment: Indeed, `distance(from:)` would a useful way to compare locations, where the default implementation of `==` is worthless. A `distance(from:isWithin:)` that let you see if two location were within a given distance of each other (where `isWithin` is expressed in meters or kilometers) would be a good extension. However, `distance(from:)` is likely a pretty expensive function. I suspect it uses the Haversine formula internally (which lets you calculate the "great circle" distance between two points on the surface of a shere).

Comment: The Haversine formula involves quite a bit of trig, which is very slow. For most applications, doing an approximation using Pythagorean distance would likely be fine, and a **WHOLE LOT** faster. You could even create a version that gave a very close approximation of the Haversine formula using Pythagorean distance and a crude approximation of a sine curve to adjust the result based on distance from the equator.

Comment: Then again, if your calculations are not time critical, don't worry about it. Just use `distance(from:)` and be done with it. You sholdn't spend time optimizing code that isn't actually a performance bottleneck to your running app. ("Premature optimization is the root of all evil" after all.)

Answer (score 0):

CLLocation class much like any class that conforms to Equatable, implements the (==) operator

And to answer your other questions I decided to start up a playground with this code

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

var str = "Hello, playground"

var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 42.0, longitude: 42.0)
var accuracy = CLLocationAccuracy.init(24.0)
var date = Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)

var loc1 = CLLocation.init(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: 44.0, horizontalAccuracy: accuracy, verticalAccuracy: accuracy, timestamp: date)
var loc2 = CLLocation.init(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: 44.0, horizontalAccuracy: accuracy, verticalAccuracy: accuracy, timestamp: date)
var loc3 = CLLocation.init(latitude: 42.0, longitude: 42.0)
var loc4 = CLLocation.init(latitude: 42.0, longitude: 42.0)
var loc5 = CLLocation.init(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: 44.0, horizontalAccuracy: accuracy, verticalAccuracy: accuracy, course: .infinity, speed: 55.0, timestamp: date)
var loc6 = CLLocation.init(coordinate: coordinate, altitude: 44.0, horizontalAccuracy: accuracy, verticalAccuracy: accuracy, course: .infinity, speed: 55.0, timestamp: date)

var bool1 = loc1 == loc2  //false
var bool2 = loc2 == loc3  //false
var bool3 = loc2 == loc2  //true
var bool4 = loc1 == loc4  //false
var bool5 = loc5 == loc6  //false
```

and the only bool that yields TRUE is bool3.

so regardless if the individual properties on different CLLocation objects are the same the == operator will not see the objects as equal. Im guessing the best way to for one to compare locations is to compare the fields off the CLLocation objects that are of interest to you

Comment: You never compared loc3 to loc4!

Comment: take it for a spin. but spoiler alert it's false

Comment: I ran a quick test in Objective-C and it appears that `CLLocation` does not override `isEqual:`. Two `CLLocation` instances are only equal if they are the same instance.

Comment: That's pretty useless. Looks like `==` is actually doing pointer comparison (`===`) since the only comparison that matches is comparing a location to itself.

Comment: "CLLocation class much like any class that conforms to Equatable, implements the (==) operator". Uh, yeah, that's axiomatic. What I meant was how does it do the comparison algorithmically?

Comment: `var loc7 = loc3.copy() as! CLLocation`;
`var bool7 = loc7 == loc3`
//This code gives false!

Comment: that is as expected

Comment: and most likely var loc8 = lov7; var bool8 = loc8 == lov7; is true

Comment: I smell an opportunity for an extension to `CLLocation` that compares just the properties you care about in your project. :)

Comment: Like I said in my comment, this is only true because of the inheritance from `NSObject`. The `CLLocation` class itself does not implement `==`.

Comment: Your statement `CLLocation class much like any class that conforms to Equatable, implements the (==) operator` is wrong.